# Horizontal and Vertical Total using Pivot table in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I followed a tutorial on creating horizontal and vertical totals using pivot tables so I got this query

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE logszxcx
AS
/* COLUMNS HEADERS */
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR (MAX)
select @columnHeaders =  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(log_date)
            from tbl_log
            group by log_date
            order by log_date
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

/* GRAND TOTAL COLUMN */
DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + 
CAST (log_date AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(log_date AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
FROM    tbl_log ORDER BY log_date
SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)

/* GRAND TOTAL ROW */
DECLARE @GrandTotalRow  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalRow = COALESCE(@GrandTotalRow + ',ISNULL(SUM([' + 
CAST(log_date AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(log_date AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
FROM tbl_log ORDER BY  log_date

/* MAIN QUERY */
DECLARE @FinalQuery NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @FinalQuery =   'SELECT *, ('+ @GrandTotalCol + ')
AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal
            FROM
                (SELECT task_id,
                       log_date
                FROM tbl_log
                ) A
            PIVOT
                (
                 COUNT (*)
                 FOR ColName
                 IN ('+@columnHeaders +')
                ) B
ORDER BY task_id
SELECT * FROM #temp_MatchesTotal UNION ALL
SELECT ''Grand Total'','''','+@GrandTotalRow +', 
ISNULL (SUM([Grand Total]),0) FROM #temp_MatchesTotal
DROP TABLE #temp_MatchesTotal'
-- PRINT 'Pivot Query '+@FinalQuery
EXECUTE(@FinalQuery)
GO
```

This creates a Stored Proc but when I'm trying to run the sp, I've got an error on the created main query which is

```
SELECT *, ('+ @GrandTotalCol + ')
    AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal
                FROM
                    (SELECT task_id,
                           log_date
                    FROM tbl_log
                    ) A
                PIVOT
                    (
                     COUNT (*)
                     FOR ColName
                     IN ('+@columnHeaders +')
                    ) B
    ORDER BY task_id
    SELECT * FROM #temp_MatchesTotal UNION ALL
    SELECT ''Grand Total'','''','+@GrandTotalRow +', 
    ISNULL (SUM([Grand Total]),0) FROM #temp_MatchesTotal
    DROP TABLE #temp_MatchesTotal
```

It says that I have an incorrect syntax near * on count and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you wanted: `COUNT (*) FOR log_date IN ('+@columnHeaders +')`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Unfortunately  error is still the same after I change it to your answer. I tried Count(log_date) for log_date then it works but my problem now is that they have unequal number of expressions.

Comment: so, it is the different error now?

Comment: Yah, I think the one I union has more or less columns than the main query

Comment: exactly. My advise is: uncomment the `PRINT 'Pivot Query '+@FinalQuery` and run the query in the SSMS. That way it should be easier to troubleshoot